# UIBezierPath Path w/ multiple line widths

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to build a design app and one of the features allows people to preview different types of custom borders on various assets.

I am trying to get these borders to draw using UIBezierPath.

Right now the system will support:

1. various border radii (anything from 0 -> a ceiling calculated elsewhere )
2. different colors for the entire border

I'm trying to implement:

1. The ability to have different border line widths.

I think I should be able to achieve this by drawing each path with a different width, but I can't figure out how to change it from path to path. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

[Click top see the border script in action](http://s28.postimg.org/jj83m3oql/Screen_Shot_2014_10_17_at_7_13_06_PM.png)

```
+(void)setBorderOnView :(id)object withWidth:(float)width andBorders:(NSArray*)borders ofColor:(UIColor*)color andRadius:(float)radius andRadii:(NSArray*)radii
{

UIView *objectView = object;

// Add half a pixel to compensate for border stroke, which puts .5 pixels outside of view.
float borderWidth = width+0.5;

float topLeftRadius = radius;
float topRightRadius = radius;
float bottomRightRadius = radius;
float bottomLeftRadius = radius;

CAShapeLayer *roundedCornerLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];


UIColor * borderColor = color;
roundedCornerLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor;

// Begin corner path
UIBezierPath *roundedCorners = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[roundedCorners moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, objectView.frame.size.height - bottomLeftRadius)];
[roundedCorners addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0 + topLeftRadius)];



if(topLeftRadius != 0){
    [roundedCorners addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(topLeftRadius, topLeftRadius)
                          radius:radius
                      startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180)
                        endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270)
                       clockwise:YES];



}


[roundedCorners addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(objectView.frame.size.width - topRightRadius, 0)];

if(topRightRadius != 0){
    [roundedCorners addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(objectView.frame.size.width - topRightRadius, 0 + topRightRadius)
                          radius:radius
                      startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270)
                        endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                       clockwise:YES];
}

[roundedCorners addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(objectView.frame.size.width, objectView.frame.size.height - bottomRightRadius)];

if(bottomRightRadius != 0){
    [roundedCorners addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(objectView.frame.size.width - bottomRightRadius, objectView.frame.size.height - bottomRightRadius)
                          radius:radius
                      startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0)
                        endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90)
                       clockwise:YES];
}

[roundedCorners addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0 + bottomLeftRadius, objectView.frame.size.height)];

if(bottomLeftRadius != 0){
    [roundedCorners addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0 + bottomLeftRadius, objectView.frame.size.height - bottomLeftRadius)
                          radius:radius
                      startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90)
                        endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180)
                       clockwise:YES];
}


roundedCornerLayer.path = roundedCorners.CGPath;
roundedCornerLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
roundedCornerLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;

[cornerMaskLayer setPath:roundedCorners.CGPath];
objectView.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;
[objectView.layer addSublayer:roundedCornerLayer];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`roundedCornerLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;` sets the width of the path. I'm not sure if you want the same path to have different widths or different paths with different widths.

If you want different widths in one path then you must break it into separate subpaths and each will have a different `lineWidth`.

If you want to have different paths then just change the value of `width` when you call the method.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. I would like to be able to do this with different line widths on each of the four sides if possible.How do subpaths work?

Comment: Since you're not actually drawing the paths but adding them as sublayers, I would say just create a different path for each side and add them to the layer.

Comment: But it's a mask so It's clipping the view. Any code sample?